# How to speed up table row scroll?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

i have a table row maded by these elements:

[image]

1 - image view (the calendar)
4 - uilabel (month, day, title, description)

on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` i fill labels in this way (the image is the same and is inserted by interface builder):

```
@try {
    newsRow = ((NewsRowController *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"]);
    if (newsRow == nil) {
        if (IS_IPAD)
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
        else [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow" owner:self options:nil];

        if ([tableArray count] > 0) {
            [newsRow setCellDataWithName:[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  
                                 andDate:[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                                     day:[dayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                   month:[monthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
    }       
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"fail.");
}
return newsRow;
```

Now, `tableArray`, `descArray`, `dayArray`, `monthArray` are NSMutableArray populated on `viewDidLoad`.

Why on iPhone device (my test is with 3G) is too slow to scroll up/down?
What i need to remove to speed up table?
This is all of my code, but i don't able to find a better solution...

**EDIT:**
[image]
I don't able to set identifier... i don't see it...
and my News Row Controller is an:

```
@interface NewsRowController : UITableViewCell
```

Any idea from the world of iphonist??? :)

thanks,
A

Comment: In addition to fluchtpunkt's specific answer to your question here, I highly recommend watching the [WWDC 2010 video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) session 131 - "Performance Optimization on iPhone OS", which has a great segment on making your table views scroll smoothly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is the reuseidentifier of your tableviewcell in the nib file correct? (you can find it in the attribute inspector)

I doubt it, because if it would be "cell" you would ask why your cells don't update.

---

Edit: Check again in interface builder if the identifier is **exactly** the same as in your code. 
[image: Interface Builder Table View Cell Identifier]

and then change your code like this:

```
if (newsRow == nil) {
    if (IS_IPAD)
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow_ipad" owner:self options:nil];
    else 
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsRow" owner:self options:nil];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Dequeue success");
}
// no matter if there was a successful dequeue or not, you have a valid cell at this point
if ([tableArray count] > 0) {
    [newsRow setCellDataWithName:[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  
                         andDate:[descArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                             day:[dayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                           month:[monthArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

see if you can see the Dequeue success logmessage

---

EDIT2

are you sure you have added a Table View Cell and not a UIView to your Nib?
I've never tried but for me it sounds possible that you can have an UIView in a nib which gets "promoted" to an TableViewCell which is added to an tableview.

My best attempt to check for this is the icon of the cell
It should look like this:
[image: cell icon]

Comment: yes, it's all correct. my table row update correctly is only too slow to scroll up/down on device..

Comment: the cells update correctly because the dequeue is never successful. If it would be successful and your cell would be reused the text wouldn't change, because you only change the text on creation of the cell.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt i don't see identifier textfield... (see my edit). I have a view that is tableviewcell....

Comment: switch to the first tab of the inspector

Comment: Yes, i have an UIView in a nib which gets "promoted" to an TableViewCell... now i added a cell and i can see Identifier. Correct. Thanks for the various edits, +1.